# Retrieve data from gridview and fill into mysql

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
I have a gridview which is being populated at runtime(using sessions) by entering the respective values in the web form. 
Now i want to retrieve all the data from that gridview and fill it into my table(MySql table)..

How can i do that???
```

//creating datatable

```
 private DataTable CreateDataTable2()
    {
        DataTable myDataTable2 = new DataTable();
        DataColumn myDataColumn;

        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Sim Imei";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Mobile Number";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Sim ID";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "IssuedForAccount";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "IssuedForDevice";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Device Imei";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Issued By";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Invoice Number";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Invoice Date";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Issued To";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Authority Name";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);


        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Company Name";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);


        myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
        myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Company Address";
        myDataTable2.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);




        return myDataTable2;
    }
//creating function to add data
private void AddDataToTable2(string SimImei, string MobileNumber, string SimID, string  IssuedForAccount, string IssuedForDevice, string DeviceImei, string IssuedBy, string InvoiceNumber, string InvoiceDate, string IssuedTo, string AuthorityName, string CompanyName, string Address, DataTable myTable)
    {
        DataRow row = myTable.NewRow();
        row["Sim Imei"] = SimImei;
        row["Mobile Number"] = MobileNumber;
        row["Sim ID"] = SimID;
        row["IssuedForAccount"] = IssuedForAccount;
        row["IssuedForDevice"] = IssuedForDevice;
        row["Device Imei"] = DeviceImei;
        row["Issued By"] = IssuedBy;
        row["Invoice Number"] = InvoiceNumber;
        row["Invoice Date"] = InvoiceDate;
        row["Issued To"] = IssuedTo;
        row["Authority Name"] = AuthorityName;
        row["Company Name"] = CompanyName;
        row["Company Address"] = Address;
        myTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

 public static void ShowAlertMessage(string error)
    {
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
        if (page != null)
        {
            error = error.Replace("'", "\'");
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "err_msg", "alert('" + error + "');", true);
        }
    }
```

//button on click the values are enetered into the gridview

```
protected void btn_InsertSim_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reporting tableValues = new reporting();

        int t = 0;
        int price = 0;

        try
        {

            #region Insert values in gridview
            connection.Open();
            string devicetyp = null;
            string mobile = null;

            try
            {


                string mobiledata="select MobileNumber from siminventoryin where  SimImei='"+txt_SubjectIMEI.Text+"'";
                MySqlCommand cmd5=new MySqlCommand (mobiledata,connection);
                cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MySqlDataReader rdr=cmd5.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                     mobile = (string)rdr["MobileNumber"];
                }
                rdr.Close();


                string devicedata = "select Devicetype from deviceinventoryin where                  DeviceIMEI='" + ddl_adjoiningdeviceSerial.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
                MySqlCommand cmd6 = new MySqlCommand(devicedata, connection);
                cmd6.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MySqlDataReader rd = cmd6.ExecuteReader();
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    devicetyp = (string)rd["DeviceType"];
                }
                rd.Close();
                AddDataToTable2(txt_SubjectIMEI.Text, mobile, txt_SubjectID.Text, ddl_accountid.SelectedValue, devicetyp, ddl_adjoiningdeviceSerial.SelectedValue, txt_issuedby.Text, txt_invoiceno.Text, txt_invoicedate.Text, txt_issuedto.Text, txt_name.Text, txt_compname.Text, txt_address.Text, (DataTable)Session["myDatatable2"]);


                grd_showsim.DataSource = ((DataTable)Session["myDatatable2"]).DefaultView;
                grd_showsim.DataBind();



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowAlertMessage(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {

            }
            #endregion
        }
        catch
        {
            ShowAlertMessage("Oops, Some error occured... We are working on it");
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            //txt_SubjectID.Text = "";
            //txt_SubjectIMEI.Text = "";

        }
    }
    #endregion
```

//databound of gridview

```
protected void grd_showsim_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
Label lblSerial = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSerial");
lblSerial.Text = i.ToString();
i++;
}
}
```

Please help...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a foreach on your gridview control & reference each individual Template Control or by using Eval. Something like

```
try{
 foreach (GridViewRow gr in YourGridView.Rows)
 {
    TextBox tb1 = ((TextBox) gr.FindControl("YourControlId1")).Text;
    TextBox tb2 = ((TextBox) gr.FindControl("YourControlId2")).Text;
    // Insert to Database here
    // Open Connection ; ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // log exception
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Damien..! your code worked like magic..! Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: @Bhuwan Devshali. I am glad it worked for you. If you liked my answer you can upvote & mark it as answer. Thank you. Damien.

Comment: @Bhawan Hey, if it worked for you like magic why did you unaccepted my answer ? Instead you made a new post and marked it as answer :( Damien.

Comment: I DONT KNOW HOW THIS HAPPENED.. i ACCEPTED YOUR ANSWER.. SORRY :(